# The DDL statement was used in the stored procedure, and the rollback did not take effect

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I wanted to roll back the data after catching an exception, but it didn't take effect.

My stored procedure is as follows：

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE CLEAN_YQCALLSDR (
    saveMonths IN INTEGER, ret OUT VARCHAR2 ) AS
BEGIN
    ret := 0;
        FOR rec IN (SELECT partition_name, high_value FROM user_tab_partitions WHERE table_name = 'a')
        LOOP
            IF to_date(substr(rec.high_value, 11, 10), 'yyyy-mm-dd') BETWEEN add_months(SYSDATE, -24) AND add_months(SYSDATE, -saveMonths) THEN
                                 execute IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE a DROP PARTITION ' || rec.partition_name;
                -- Artificially created anomalies
                                ret := ret/0;
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            -- 回滚事务
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('sqlcode : ' || sqlcode);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('sqlerrm : ' || sqlerrm);
            ret := 1;
            ROLLBACK;
END;
```

Answer (score 4):

What did you want to roll back? `ALTER TABLE`? That's a DDL, you can't roll it back because it (a DDL) performs

- implicit `commit` before executing actual statement,
- executes it (i.e. alters the table). That might, or might not be executed - perhaps you'll hit some error

  - if everything is OK, Oracle implicitly commits again
  - if it fails and you want to roll back, there's nothing to roll back because of the *first step's* implicit commit

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you very much for your reply. Tomorrow will be even better because of you